# If 'this' keyword can not be used inside a static method then how is method1() calling method2() in the given code?

Tags: java, this, static-methods, method-call, instance-methods

```
  public class Main {
  static void method1()
   {
       System.out.println("In method1");
       method2(); //Is this equivalent to this.method2()?
   }
   static void method2()
   {
       System.out.println("In method2");
   }
   public static void main(String args[]) {
       Main.method1();
   }
}
```

Is the commented line equivalent to `this.method2()`? Because in the case of instance method `this` is automatically added by the compiler but I have read that static method cannot refer to `this`. If `this` is not been referred here how is method call for `method2()` taking place?

Comment: Main is the whole class, its not an instance, hence its possible to call in that case.

Comment: `method1` can call `method2` because they both are static and are defined in same class

Answer (score 2):

A `class` is an abstract-ish set of objects, defined by their object reference, characterized by their attributes (which are the data members) and their abilities (that is, their methods).

Let's start with what you are correct about: an instance, that is, an object can be referred to inside its methods via the keyword of `this`. What you do *not* understand is that `static` means `class`-level. When we are speaking about `class`-level methods, there is no instance to refer to and `this` makes no sense.

In your example, you are calling a `class`-level method inside another `class`-level method. No `this` involved here, neither explicitly, nor implicitly.

Let's consider an analogy:

Let's consider the set of `Bird`. An instance of `Bird` can `.fly()`, the whole class of Bird cannot `.fly()`, because while a `Bird` instance flies, the other is sitting on her eggs. However, birds may have collective actions, like `.flyInFlock()`. A single `Bird` instance cannot `.flyInFlock()`, but `Bird`, as a `class` can do it, because it's `class`-level, which is referred to by the static keyword.

Instance-level methods can be called via:

- an object reference, like bird.fly()
- via `this` inside an instance-level method of the `class`, like `this.fly()`
- via its name, with the same condition as the second case here, as `fly()`

What your example does is that a collective, `class`-level method calls another collective, `class`-level method of the same `class`. There is no illegal drop from `class`-level to instance-level in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Using `this` keyword means this instance of the `Main` class. The line you are using is equal to `Main.method2()` not `this.method2()`. If you were using a method that is not static, then it would be equal to `this.method2()`. A static method belongs to the class, not to an instance of that class. Therefore it cannot be referred `this`, which is an instance of the class.

Answer (score 1):

The keyword `this` always refers to the current instance of a class that you are "working in right now". Inside a static method there can be no object instance and thus no `this` available because the static method by definition exists independently of any instances. This also means you can not call any non-static method of your class inside a static method because there is just no `this` available.

You are free to call any static method from any place though, *because* they're independent of instances. This is why `method1()` can call `method2()`.

Additionally you can (but don't have to) specify the class name, as you did when calling `Main.method1()`. Removing the leading `Main.` would result in the same call, as you're referring to a static method within the same class. The same applies for the call to `method2()`. Here you could instead add the class name, making the call look like `Main.method2()` and it would result in the same call.

This namespacing thing only starts making sense when calling static methods of *different* classes and you need to specify which class you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Both methods are static.

- you cannot use `this` in a static method.
- you can reference other static methods

Lets check the generated bytecode

```
static method1()V
   L0
    LINENUMBER 6 L0
    GETSTATIC java/lang/System.out : Ljava/io/PrintStream;
    LDC "In method1"
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/io/PrintStream.println (Ljava/lang/String;)V
   L1
    LINENUMBER 7 L1
    INVOKESTATIC mypackage/Main.method2 ()V
   L2
    LINENUMBER 8 L2
    RETURN
    MAXSTACK = 2
    MAXLOCALS = 0
```

You can see that `INVOKESTATIC mypackage/Main.method2 ()V` references the classname and method name.